# How to restrict cursor movement in a C# Windows form?

Tags: c#, cursor

Can someone give me a sample code to confine the cursor on to a Form. I found this ([ClipCursor API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that says it can be done using it). I have a C# Windows form application and using VS 2008.

My code:

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void Form1_CursorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            MoveCursor ();

    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveCursor();
    }

    private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveCursor();
    }

    private void MoveCursor()
    {
        Cursor.Clip = Bounds;
       this.Capture = true;
    }
  }
 }
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
    partial class Form1
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Required designer variable.
      /// </summary>
       private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] {
        "all",
        "allah",
        "allo"});
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 70);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(227, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 264);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.No;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.CursorChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_CursorChanged);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);
        this.LocationChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_LocationChanged);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option that doesn't require you to p/invoke: [Cursor.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx)

Edit:  new code.  Complete form code in single file.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
     public Form1()     {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
      private void Form1_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)     {
          MoveCursor ();
      }
      private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)     {
         MoveCursor();
     }
      private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)     {
         MoveCursor();
     }
      private void MoveCursor()
      {
         this.Capture = true;
         System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Clip = Bounds;
     }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
         this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
         this.SuspendLayout();
         this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] {"all", "allak", "allo"});
         this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
         this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
         this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 70);
         this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
         this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(227, 20);
         this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
         this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
         this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
         this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 264);
         this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
         this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.No;
         this.Name = "Form1";
         this.Text = "Form1";
         this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Activate);
         this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);
         this.LocationChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_LocationChanged);
         this.ResumeLayout(false);
         this.PerformLayout();
      }
      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {
         if (disposing && (components != null))
            components.Dispose();
         base.Dispose(disposing);
      }
      private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

      private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1 = null;
   }
}
```

Unless this is a particularly locked-down computer like a kiosk, users will probably hate it.  Think about if they are needing to alt+tab to a different app to copy something to the clipboard to fill out your form...  Just be careful.

Comment: How do i make use of this method ? where should i include this code, and from where should i call this method ?  I am looking for a code, where a user can move the mouse only on the application it self. I am using VS 2008. and its a form application.

The user should be only able to move the mouse on the application, not on any desktop components or etc. Can this be done with the above code ?

Comment: If it was me, I would only call it from Form_Load and Form_LocationChanged.  And hopefully this is only supposed to be in effect while a Modal Dialog is up.  `using (var frm = new MyForm ()){frm.ShowDialog();Cursor.Clip = Screen.Bounds;}`. Also, you'll need to capture the mouse.  I'll add content to my answer.

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution to this problem, The mouse still can be visible outside the Form (C# windows forms application). Help appreciated :(

Comment: It has very little teeth, Ctrl+Esc lets you escape the trap.

Comment: @illep, not sure why it didn't work for you.  Try the new solution instead.

Comment: @agent-j Still its the same, i have pasted my code above, wonder if i had made any mistake. :S

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  Can you add your InitializeComponent method?

Comment: I am using Windows Vista, VS 2008.  i can initialize the 'InitializeComponent ' method, and the GUI is popping up as well. but the Cursor can be moved out of the Form, and click as well. :(

Comment: What happens if you put a button on the form and in button_onclick, you call MoveCursor()?

Comment: @agent-j  No, sadly i can't do that. It requires something like onLoad () :S. Did the program work for you ?

Comment: I need your InitializeComponent method... otherwise the event handles don't get added.  Can you post it (it's in Form1.Designer.cs)

Comment: @agent-j I have added it above.

Comment: @illep, I have posted a file that works on my machine.  Can you see if it works on yours.  Note that I got rid of the .designer.cs file.

Comment: WoW.. yeah that's awesome :D Works great, but the cursor doesn't appear it loads (as in the rotating circle sign comes in). Thanks loads