# C# SharpDX Lock Cursor inside Window

Tags: c#, .net-core, 3d, sharpdx

So i am making a game.

How do i make my game still detect cursor movement even if it has reached the edge of the screen and cannot move?

This is my code

```
        float rotationX = 0;
        float rotationY = 0;
        float dist = 1;

        float clmp(float val, float min, float max)
        {
            if (val >= max) return max; 
            if(val <= min) return min; 
            return val;
        }

        Control.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
        {
            var yRotate = lastX - e.X;
            var xRotate = lastY - e.Y;
            rotationX += xRotate * moveFactor;
            rotationY -= yRotate * moveFactor;
            lastY = e.Y;
            lastX = e.X;

            rotationX = clmp(rotationX, -1.5f, 1.5f);

            float h = MathF.Cos(rotationX) * dist;
            Vector3 cameraTarget = new Vector3(MathF.Cos(rotationY) * h, MathF.Sin(rotationX) * dist, MathF.Sin(rotationY) * h);

            viewMatrix = Matrix.LookAtRH(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraTarget, cameraUp);
        };
```

How do i make it still rotate the camera, if the cursor is outside the Window and / or cannot move anymore (for example it has reached the Clipping corner)?

Or like unity's

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
```

I have tried Clip and as soon as it reaches the corner you cant move the camera anymore.

Cheers!

(No, [How to restrict cursor movement in a C# Windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484824/how-to-restrict-cursor-movement-in-a-c-sharp-windows-form), is NOT an answer, as it uses clip and has absolutely nothing to do with a fps mouse.)

Comment: It's at least the 3rd time your asking for this, but we'll keep closing it as duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74836204/c-sharp-lock-cursor-inside-of-window-like-blender-does-it) until you explain how this is different from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484824/how-to-restrict-cursor-movement-in-a-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: @SimonMourier cos that is not the answer im looking for

Comment: You use Control.MouseMove, this is pure Winforms, what do you mean by an "FPS mouse"?

Comment: First Person Shooter mouse, a mouse that never leaves the control and when it enters one side it goes to the other to not make the game experience stop

Comment: that's what clip does. have you even tried this solution? explain what you have tried or this will be closed again